# Why logging module works from CLI but not from Crontab?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, cron, pynput

I'm trying to schedule a python script as a cron job. If I run the script from terminal it works fine, If I schedule the script in crontab, nothing happens(that means that if I execute:
`$ grep -i cron /var/log/syslog` there's no error).

That python script is supposed to get the user's mouse actions using pynput module. It also uses the logging module in order to save the mouse actions into a .txt file. In addition, it calls some functions from a file called utitlites.py

**Here's the cronjob**

```
* * * * * /home/alex/Desktop && /usr/bin/python3 mouselogger.py
```

**Here's mouselogger.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from threading import Timer
from pynput.mouse import Listener
import logging
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(
    os.path.realpath(__file__)), "../"))

from Functions import utils as ut

if __name__=='__main__':

    #ut.initialize_dirs()
    rec_file = ''.join(('mouse_',ut.get_date(),'.txt'))
    raw_data = ut.get_name('Mouse')
    rec_file = os.path.join(raw_data,rec_file)
    logging.basicConfig(filename=rec_file,level=logging.DEBUG,format="%(asctime)s    %(message)s")

    try:
        with Listener(on_move=ut.on_move, on_click=ut.on_click,on_scroll=ut.on_scroll) as listener:
            Timer(60, listener.stop).start()
            listener.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt as err:
        print(err)
        sys.exit(0)

    print('Exiting logger...')
```

**Here's utilities.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from serial import Serial
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import collections
import logging
import shutil
import serial
import time
import sys
import os

click_held = False
button = None


def on_move(x,y):
    """The callback to call when mouse move events occur

    Args:
        x (float): The new pointer position
        y (float): The new pointer poisition
    """
    if click_held:
        logging.info("MV    {0:>8}  {1:>8}  {2:>8}:".format(x,y,str(None)))
    else:
        logging.info("MV    {0:>8}  {1:>8}  {2:>8}:".format(x,y,str(None)))


def on_click(x,y,button,pressed):
    """The callback to call when a mouse button is clicked

    Args:
        x (float): Mouse coordinates on screen
        y (float): Mouse coordinates on screen
        button (str): one of the Button values
        pressed (bool): Pressed is whether the button was pressed
    """
    global click_held
    if pressed:
        click_held = True
        logging.info("CLK    {0:>7}    {1:>6}    {2:>13}".format(x,y,button))
    else:
        click_held = False
        logging.info("RLS    {0:>7}    {1:>6}    {2:>13}".format(x,y,button))


def on_scroll(x,y,dx,dy):
    """The callback to call when mouse scroll events occur

    Args:
        x (float): The new pointer position on screen
        y (float): The new pointer position on screen
        dx (int): The horizontal scroll. The units of scrolling is undefined
        dy (int): The vertical scroll. The units of scrolling is undefined
    """
    if dy == -1:
        logging.info("SCRD    {0:>6}    {1:>6}    {2:>6}".format(x,y,str(None)))
    elif dy == 1:
        logging.info("SCRU    {0:>6}    {1:>6}    {2:>6}".format(x,y,str(None)))
    else:
        pass


def on_press_keys(key):
    """The callback to call when a button is pressed.

    Args:
        key (str): A KeyCode,a Key or None if the key is unknown
    """
    subkeys = [
    'Key.alt','Key.alt_gr','Key.alt_r','Key.backspace',
    'Key.space','Key.ctrl','Key.ctrl_r','Key.down',
    'Key.up','Key.left','Key.right','Key.page_down',
    'Key.page_up','Key.enter','Key.shift','Key.shift_r'
    ]

    key = str(key).strip('\'')
    if(key in subkeys):
        #print(key)
        logging.info(key)
    else:
        pass


def record_chair(output_file):
    """Read the data stream coming from the serial monitor
       in order to get the sensor readings

    Args:
        output_file (str): The file name, where the data stream will be stored
    """
    serial_port = "/dev/ttyACM0"
    baud_rate = 9600
    ser = serial.Serial(serial_port,baud_rate)
    logging.basicConfig(filename=output_file,level=logging.DEBUG,format="%(asctime)s    %(message)s")
    flag = False
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < 60.0:
        try:
            serial_data = str(ser.readline().decode().strip('\r\n'))
            time.sleep(0.2)
            tmp = serial_data.split('  ')[0] #Getting Sensor Id
            if(tmp == 'A0'):
                flag = True
            if (flag and tmp != 'A4'):
                #print(serial_data)
                logging.info(serial_data)
            if(flag and tmp == 'A4'):
                flag = False
                #print(serial_data)
                logging.info(serial_data)
        except (UnicodeDecodeError, KeyboardInterrupt) as err:
            print(err)
            print(err.args)
            sys.exit(0)


def initialize_dirs():
    """Create the appropriate directories in order to save
       and process the collected data
    """
    current_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
    os.chdir('..')
    current_path = (os.path.abspath(os.curdir)) #/Multodal_User_Monitoring
    current_path = os.path.join(current_path,'Data')
    create_subdirs([current_path])

    #Create mouse log folder
    mouse = os.path.join(current_path,'Mouse')
    create_subdirs([mouse])
    #Create mouse subfolders
    names = concat_names(mouse)
    create_subdirs(names)

    #Create keyboard log  folder
    keyboard = os.path.join(current_path,'Keyboard')
    create_subdirs([keyboard])
    #Create keyboard subfolders
    names = concat_names(keyboard)
    create_subdirs(names)

    #Create the chair log folder
    chair = os.path.join(current_path,'Chair')
    create_subdirs([chair])
    #Create chair subfolders
    names = concat_names(chair)
    create_subdirs(names)

    #Create webcam log folder
    webcam = os.path.join(current_path,'Webcam')
    create_subdirs([webcam])

def concat_names(dir) -> str:
    """Concatenate the given folder names
       with the appropriate path

    Args:
        dir (str): The directory to create the subfolders

    Returns:
        list: The new absolute paths
    """
    raw_data = os.path.join(dir,'Raw')
    edited_data = os.path.join(dir,'Edited_logs')
    csv_data = os.path.join(dir,'CSV')
    features = os.path.join(dir,'Features')
    dirs = [raw_data,edited_data,csv_data,features]
    return dirs


def create_subdirs(paths):
    """Create sub directories given some absolute paths

    Args:
        paths (list): A list containing the paths to be created
    """
    for index,path in enumerate(paths):
        if(os.path.isdir(paths[index])):
            pass
        else:
            os.mkdir(paths[index])


def round_down(num,divisor) -> int:
    """Round the number of lines contained into the recording file,
       down to the nearest multiple of the given divisor

    Args:
        num (int): The number of lines contained into the given log file
        divisor (int): The divisor in order to get tuples of divisor

    Returns:
        int: The nearest multiple of five
    """
    return num-(num%divisor)


def get_date() -> str:
    """Get the current date in order to properly name
       the recored log files
    Returns:
        str: The current date in: YY_MM_DD format
    """
    return datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d')


def get_name(modality) -> str:
    """Save the recorded log into /Data/<Modality_name>/Raw

    Args:
        modality (str): The log data source

    Returns:
        str: The absolute path where each recording is saved
    """
    current_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
    current_path = os.path.join(current_path,'Data')

    if modality == 'Chair':
        chair_path = os.path.join(current_path,modality,'Raw')
        return chair_path

    elif modality == 'Mouse':
        mouse_path = os.path.join(current_path,modality,'Raw')
        return mouse_path

    elif modality == 'Keyboard':
        keyboard_path = os.path.join(current_path,modality,'Raw')
        return keyboard_path


def crawl_dir(target,folder) -> str:
    """Enumerate all the given files in a directory
       based on the given file extension

    Args:
        target (str): The file to search for
        folder (str): The folder to search

    Returns:
        [type]: A list containing the file names
    """
    current_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
    path = os.path.join(current_path,folder)
    file_names =[]
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if(f.endswith(target)):
            fname=os.path.join(path,f)
            file_names.append(fname)
    return file_names


def convert_keys2_csv(input_file,output_file):
    """Convert the data stream file(keylogger recording) from .txt to .csv format

    Args:
        input_file (str): The data stream file in .txt format
        output_file (str): The csv extension file name
    """
    df = pd.read_fwf(input_file)
    col_names = ['Date','Time','Key']
    df.to_csv(output_file,header=col_names,encoding='utf-8',index=False)


def convert_mouse2_csv(input_file,output_file):
    """Convert the data stream file(mouselogger recording) from .txt to .csv format

    Args:
        input_file (str): The data stream file in .txt format
        output_file (str): The csv extension file name
    """
    df = pd.read_fwf(input_file)
    col_names = ['Date','Time','Action','PosX','PosY','Button']
    df.to_csv(output_file,header=col_names,encoding='utf-8',index=False)


def convert_chair_2_csv(input_file,output_file):
    """Convert the data stream file(chair recording)
       from .txt to .csv format

    Args:
        input_file (str): The data stream file in .txt format
        output_file (str): The csv extension file name
    """
    if(os.path.isfile(input_file)):
        pass
    else:
        print('Invalid working directory...')
        print('Aborting...')
        sys.exit(0)

    tmp0,tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4 = 0,1,2,3,4

    line_number = 0
    for line in open(input_file).readlines():
        line_number += 1

    rounded_line = round_down(line_number,5)
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)

    with open(input_file,'r') as f1:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        for i in range(rounded_line // 5):
            #Sensor:Analog input 0 values
            Sid0 = lines[i+tmp0]
            temp = Sid0.split()
            d['Sid0'].append([temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3]])
            #Sensor:Analog input 1 values
            Sid1 = lines[i+tmp1]
            temp = Sid1.split()
            d['Sid1'].append([temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3]])
            #Sensor:Analog input 2 values
            Sid2 = lines[i+tmp2]
            temp = Sid2.split()
            d['Sid2'].append([temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3]])
            #Sensor:Analog input 3 values
            Sid3 = lines[i+tmp3]
            temp = Sid3.split()
            d['Sid3'].append([temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3]])
            #Sensor:Analog input 4 values
            Sid4 = lines[i+tmp4]
            temp = Sid4.split()
            d['Sid4'].append([temp[0],temp[1],temp[2],temp[3]])

            tmp0 += 4
            tmp1 += 4
            tmp2 += 4
            tmp3 += 4
            tmp4 += 4

    l = []
    for i in range(rounded_line // 5):
        date = d['Sid0'][i][0]
        time = d['Sid0'][i][1]
        A0_val = d['Sid0'][i][3]
        A1_val = d['Sid1'][i][3]
        A2_val = d['Sid2'][i][3]
        A3_val = d['Sid3'][i][3]
        A4_val = d['Sid4'][i][3]
        l.append([date,time,A0_val,A1_val,A2_val,A3_val,A4_val])

    sensor_readings_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(l)
    sensor_readings_df.columns = ['Date','Time','A0','A1','A2','A3','A4']
    sensor_readings_df.to_csv(output_file, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
    del l


def parse_raw_data(modality):
    """Convert each modality's raw data into csv format and move
       the edited raw data into the appropriate Edited_logs folder

    Args:
        modality (str): The data source
    """
    #Change directories
    current_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) #/Functions
    os.chdir('..')
    current_path = (os.path.abspath(os.curdir)) #/Multimodal_User_Monitoring
    os.chdir('./Data')#/Multimodal_User_Monitoring/Data
    current_path = (os.path.abspath(os.curdir)) #/Multimodal_User_Monitoring/Data
    current_path = os.path.join(current_path,modality) #example: /Multimodal_User_Monitoring/Data/<Modality>
    raw_data_path = os.path.join(current_path,'Raw')
    csv_data_path = os.path.join(current_path,'CSV')
    edited_logs_path = os.path.join(current_path,'Edited_logs')

    txt_names = crawl_dir('.txt',raw_data_path)
    csv_names = []
    for elem in txt_names:
        name = elem.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
        csv_name = name+'.csv'
        tmp = os.path.join(csv_data_path,csv_name)
        csv_names.append(tmp)

    if modality == 'Mouse':
        if len(txt_names) == len(csv_names):
            for i, elem in enumerate(txt_names):
            #for i in range(len(txt_names)):
                convert_mouse2_csv(txt_names[i],csv_names[i])
                shutil.move(txt_names[i],edited_logs_path)

    elif modality == 'Keyboard':
        if len(txt_names) == len(csv_names):
            for i, elem in enumerate(txt_names):
            #for i in range(len(txt_names)):
                convert_keys2_csv(txt_names[i],csv_names[i])
                shutil.move(txt_names[i],edited_logs_path)

    elif modality == 'Chair':
        if len(txt_names) == len(csv_names):
            for i, elem in enumerate(txt_names):
            #for i in range(len(txt_names)):
                convert_chair_2_csv(txt_names[i],csv_names[i])
                shutil.move(txt_names[i],edited_logs_path)
```